# Camera remains turned on seconds after being stopped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My camera is acting weird. When I take a picture, it will turn off right away. But when my component unmounts, it can take up to 10 seconds before my camera turns off, even though the exact same function is being called. I assume it's still turned on since the "camera light" is still turned on. Here's the logic behind:

```
class Webcam extends React.Component<Props> {
...
videoRef: any = React.createRef();

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.destroyCam();
}

destroyCam() {
    this.videoRef.srcObject.getTracks().forEach((track: MediaStream) => {
    track.stop();
  });
}

onShoot = () => {
  var timer = setInterval(() => {
    this.countdown--;
    if (this.countdown === 0) {
      this.destroyCam();
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
};

render() {
  return(
    ...
    <video ref={el => (this.videoRef = el)}/>
  )
}
}
```

Like I said, when the onShoot is fired, it turns off the camera immediately. Why doesn't it when unmounting the component?

Comment: I'm thinking the problem isn't in the code you provided. My guess is that your component isn't actually unmounting until later. How do you know it is unmounting? Run in debug mode or add a `console.log` in `componentWillUnmount` to test

Comment: (side note:) Shouldn't you also destroy your timer when unmounting?

Comment: I'm sure its unmounted, I have done the console.log. I can even run console.log in the destroyCam function aswell when it unmounts